# Geometry Nodes creating very dark textures in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

I'm creating a hexagon core. The inner core for some reason is black in cycles

[image]

If I move the inner core up just a titch the black goes away but it's still darker.

[image]

Looks completely normal in eevee

[image]

Here is the geometry nodes setup.

[image]
And here is the file https://blend-exchange.com/b/6Z0vM0On

Comment: This is because you accidentally duplicated your base mesh of the core. that's why the shapes end up overlapping.

Comment: That was it. Make it as an answer and I can give you them points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have obviously accidentally duplicated the base mesh of the core.

You can easily fix this by selecting some single vertices, extending the selection to the linked vertices with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, and remove them with <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image]

*PS: Another possibility is of course to merge the vertices using the `Merge by Distance` option.*